# Issue with Cloud Datastore backup in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I use an App Enginge Datastore backup file and create a BigQuery table. The issue I face is all the JSON values are treated as 'Flattened strings' by default.

I couldn't access the repeated string value for example as below. Value is for column: qoption

```
[{
  "optionId": 0,
  "optionTitle": "All inclusive",
  "optionImageUrl": "http://sampleurl",
  "masterCatInfo": 95680,
  "brInfo": 56502428160,
  "category": "",
  "tags": ["Holiday"]
}, {
  "optionId": 1,
  "optionTitle": "Self catered",
  "optionImageUrl": "http://sampleurl1",
  "masterCatInfo": 520280,
  "brId": 56598160,
  "category": "",
  "tags": ["Holiday"]
}]
```

Is it possibe to again recreate existing table as in JSON format , ideally through BQ CLI, so that I can access table qoption.optionId, qoption.optionTitle,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Nested and Repeated Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested). Basically you have to manually setup your bigquery schema with a nested data schema. Once that is done and your data is imported you should be able to use your nested properties.

Alternatively big query can [parse your json ad-hoc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions).